# nodejs, NotFoundError: Not Found - SendStream.error (...\node_modules\serve-static\index.js:121:7) message: 'Not Found' }

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am facing a difficulty with this error. Although the node api does respond ok and it seems this is not affecting executing I would still like to know what am I getting this error? Has any faced this before?

```
{ NotFoundError: Not Found
    at ...\app.js:37:8
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (...\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (...\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
    at ...\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (...\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (...\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at ...\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:635:15
    at next (...\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:260:14)
    at Function.handle (...\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
    at router (...\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (...\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (...\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
    at ...\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (...\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Development\Dekoll\SMSManager\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at SendStream.error (...\node_modules\serve-static\index.js:121:7) message: 'Not Found' }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not Found error in node essentially means the file you looking might not been found, if this is from server side, `ctrl + c` the server and do a fresh start.

But essentially node throws this error typically when the module, file or something it looks is not present in the project module